# Как реализованы ссылки на методы в Java 8 внутри JVM?

Tags: java, lambda

Мне стало интересно, как реализованы ссылки на методы(`::`) в Java 8.
Для сравнения опишу, как они реализованы в Object Pascal - простейшим образом и эффективно. Указатель на метод в нем это запись из двух указателей:

```
TMethod = record
  Code, Data: Pointer;
end;
```

В одном хранится адрес процедуры, в другом - адрес объекта-владельца.

```
Button1.OnClick = MyClick1;
```

транслируется всего лишь в копирование двух указателей.
Вызов такого метода - это вызов процедуры по адресу, с передачей неявного параметра this.

Но мне здесь сказали, что в Java 8 ссылки на методы это синтаксический сахар и что за ними скрывается что то страшное. Неужели это и правда так? Кто нибудь смотрел, в какой код на JVM транслируются ссылки на методы?

Comment: @AntonSorokin а лямбды сами по себе - штука очень непростая. Это инструкция `invokedynamic`, вызывающая созданный компилятором bootstrap-метод, который в рантайме с помощью [LambdaMetafactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) создаёт [CallSite](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/CallSite.html), который возвращает [MethodHandle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html), который уже будет вызван.

Comment: Тема крайне интересная. Как раз на недавнем JPoint был доклад... Продолжительностью в два с половиной часа.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, а вы уверены, что в случае ссылок на методы через лямбда-выражение делается? Ведь в случае ссылки на функцию уже и объект существует, и функция есть.

Comment: @Eugene о да, я уверен :) Достаточно много времени провожу под капотом JVM, своими глазами видел.

Comment: @Eugene во первых, в книгах по "ФИ" на Java ссылки на методы обычно описываются в главах про лямбды. Во вторых, вот: `System.out::println` equivalent to `x -> System.out.println(x)`, `Math::max` equivalent to `(x,y) -> Math.max(x,y)`, `String::length `equivalent to   `                                                                                                                        x -> x.length()`

Comment: Зачем все так сложно? Есть ли тому объективные причины? Ведь тип функции известен на этапе компиляции.

Comment: @Eugene я понимаю, что вы обращались не ко мне, но все таки: про какие именно сложности вы говорите? Потому что я там не вижу никаких нестыковок

Comment: Anton Sorokin, я обращаюсь ко всем, кто знает. Под сложностями понимаю создание фабрики и MethodHandle. Зачем? Ведь метод уже есть.

Comment: @Eugene параметры для вызова могут быть разными, но обычно вызывается кешированная версия. Это для лямбды. Ссылки на методы вызываются проще - синтаксический метод не генерируется. Впрочем, в моем ответе вроде это все описано

Comment: Кстати, хочу напомнить, что вам следует принять ответ, который помог вам - для этого нажмите на галочку рядом с ответом. Ну и на стрелку вверх. И советую проделать это с другими вашими вопросами, потому что у вас нет ни одного принятого ответа, хотя сами ответы(которые полностью отвечают на ваши вопросы) есть.

Comment: Я хотел принять, но не знал как. Думал может у меня репутация еще не позволяет это делать. С этим вопросом я еще немного подожду, а в старых сделаю..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В Java ссылки на методы - это сокращенные лямбда-выражения:

Всего существует 3 конструкции ссылок на методы:

1. `object::instanceMethod` -  ссылается на объектный метод предложенного объекта
2. `Class::staticMethod` - ссылается на статический метод класса
3. `Class::instanceMethod` - ссылается на объектный метод предложенного объекта. Действует, так же как в п.1, только с именем класса

Примеры реализации этих конструкций и их лямбда-аналоги ниже:

1. `System.out::println` равно `x -> System.out.println(x)`
2. `Math::max` равно `(x,y) -> Math.max(x,y)`
3. `String::length` равно `x -> x.length()`

Но все таки, ссылки на методы реализуются немного по-разному(об этом ниже).

По сути, лямбда выражения похожи на анонимные классы с одним методом, но реализованы по другому. Подробный разбор их реализации - ниже.

---

Краткая выборка из [статьи, про то, как лямбды работают под капотом JVM](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-8-Lambdas-A-Peek-Under-the-Hood):

> Анонимные внутренние классы имеют нежелательные характеристики,
> которые могут повлиять на производительность вашего приложения.
> Сначала компилятор генерирует новый файл класса для каждого анонимного
> внутреннего класса.  Создание многих файлов классов нежелательно,
> поскольку каждый файл класса должен быть загружен и проверен перед
> использованием, что влияет на производительность при запуске
> приложения. Если бы лямбды были переведены в анонимные внутренние
> классы, у вас был бы новый файл класса для каждой лямбды. Как
> следствие, анонимные внутренние классы увеличат потребление памяти
> вашим приложением.

Вместо использования для лямбда-выражений отдельного класса версия Java 8 опирается на байткод-инструкцию `invokedynamic`, добавленную в версии Java 7. Инструкция `invokedynamic` ориентирована на bootstrap-метод, который, в свою очередь, создает реализацию лямбда-выражения при первом вызове этого метода.

Перевод лямбда-выражения в байт-код выполняется в два этапа:

1. Генерируется динамическая лямбда-фабрика, которая при вызове возвращает экземпляр [функционального интерфейса](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), в который преобразовывается лямбда.
2. Тело лямбда-выражения преобразовывается в метод, который будет вызываться с помощью  `invokedynamic`.

В случае ссылок на методы все происходит почти также, как и для лямбд - но javac не генерирует синтаксический метод(потому что он уже есть в классе из которого вызывается метод, а у лямбды такого класса нет), и может ссылаться на нужный метод напрямую.

Чтобы проиллюстрировать первый шаг, давайте рассмотрим байткод, сгенерированный из простого класса, содержащего лямбду:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Lambda {
    Function<String, Integer> f = s -> Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

Этот класс сгенерируется в следующий байткод:

```
 0: aload_0
 1: invokespecial #1 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
 4: aload_0
 5: invokedynamic #2, 0 // InvokeDynamic
                  #0:apply:()Ljava/util/function/Function;
10: putfield #3 // Field f:Ljava/util/function/Function;
13: return
```

То, как будет выполнен второй шаг, зависит от того, является ли лямбда-выражение необработанным(лямбда не обращается ни к каким переменным вне ее тела), или замыкающим(лямбда получает доступ к переменным вне ее тела).

*Примечание: замыкание - когда в лямбда выражении используется переменная, объявленная вне этого выражения.*

В первом случае, лямбда-выражения просто превращаются в статический метод, имеющий точно такую ​​же сигнатуру лямбда-выражения, и объявляются в том же классе, где используется лямбда-выражение. Например, лямбда-выражение, объявленное в классе Lambda выше, может быть преобразовано в метод, подобный этому:

```
static Integer lambda$1(String s) {
    return Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

Случай замыкания лямбда-выражения немного сложнее, поскольку замыкающие переменные должны быть переданы методу, реализующему тело лямбда-выражения вместе с формальными аргументами лямбда-выражения. В этом случае общая стратегия  заключается в использования аргументов лямбда-выражения с дополнительным аргументом для каждой внешней переменной. Давайте посмотрим на практический пример:

```
int offset = 100;
Function<String, Integer> f = s -> Integer.parseInt(s) + offset;
```

Соответствующая реализация метода будет сгенерирована так:

```
static Integer lambda$1(int offset, String s) {
    return Integer.parseInt(s) + offset;
}
```

---

Также есть цитата Брайна Гетца из [этого ответа на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30002771/7150209):

> Когда компилятор встречает лямбда-выражение, он сначала понижает тело
> лямбды в метод(аналогичный лямбде), возможно, с некоторыми
> дополнительными аргументами(если лямбда замыкающая). В момент, когда
> лямбда-выражение будет захвачено, оно генерирует *место динамического
> вызова*(CallSite object), которое при вызове возвращает экземпляр функционального
> интерфейса, в который преобразовывалось лямбда-выражение. Это место
> вызова называется лямбда-фабрикой(lambda-factory) для данной лямбды.
> Динамические аргументы лямбда-фабрики - это значения, полученные из
> лексического контекста. Метод начальной загрузки(bootstrap method)
> фабрики лямбда-выражений - это стандартизированный метод в библиотеке
> рантайма языка Java, который называется метафабрикой лямбда-выражения.
>
> Ссылки на методы обрабатываются так же, как и лямбда-выражения, за
> исключением того, что большинство ссылок на методы не нужно вводить в
> новый метод; мы можем просто загрузить дескриптор для ссылочного
> метода и передать его метафабрике.

---

UPD: Очень рекомендую эту статью с Хабра:
[Разбираем лямбда-выражения в Java](https://habr.com/ru/company/haulmont/blog/432418/)

В качестве источников я использовал две статьи - [доклад Java 8 Lambdas A Peek Under the Hood](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-8-Lambdas-A-Peek-Under-the-Hood) и [статью от IBM про лямбды](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-java8lambdas/index.html).

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что в случае ссылки на метод шаг 1 не выполняется?

Comment: @Eugene да, правильно.